# Calculate percentage of values ​based on different dates

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Want to get this [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dXSG.png
so i have 2018 as index period and need calculate difference in each year with 2018: example 2018 and 2019, 2018 and 2020, 2018 and 2021...

Need to use something like summarize total=sum(value) | where date == '2018-01-01' but how iterate each value to 2024 year?

Please help, checked Kusto doc but hav'nt find answer how to do that :(

i have this table

```
datatable(Value:int, Date:datetime) 
    [2121, datetime(2018-01-01), //100% as this is index perios
     5645, datetime(2019-01-01), // will be 266%
     5123, datetime(2020-01-01),
     4478, datetime(2024-01-01),
     9965, datetime(2024-01-01),
     7645, datetime(2024-01-01),
    ];
```

Comment: How does the image relates to your data and expected results? Where did the 4 lines come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let t = (datatable(Value:int, Date:datetime) 
    [2121, datetime(2018-01-01), //100% as this is index perios
     5645, datetime(2019-01-01), // will be 266%
     5123, datetime(2020-01-01),
     4478, datetime(2024-01-01),
     9965, datetime(2024-01-01),
     7645, datetime(2024-01-01),
    ]);
let val_2018 = toscalar(t | where Date == datetime(2018-01-01) | summarize sum(Value));
t
| summarize percent = 100.0 * sum(Value) / val_2018 by Date
| render linechart with (xcolumn=Date, ycolumns=percent)
```

[image]

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA32RwW6DMAyG75V4B18qwcRGkgEtnbjtGXaZpilQS0QKMCVmbac9/JJSNEDTEh%20S%20P/t5ItGAoISwqMkNyuN4YvUAx5URzE8S8KDyyCpFiMINuDGq%20CCxzAdh4Lx/T3jLqIYkoQztgVpgRplwUd3xDN8oFG9HQtAlqfZskAxKwAnpTVUCCLPt5ODi8eFQ7DJcVOk6W6/VKQrRVHk2f%20K3fpea8Vb9BRstEP2KfW7f7cjR72tpZYmJPiGU4MGr9igLP9E5ER2aFtp1Bf61Yg78oUp2MyTDlmNnf8ch/SBwd1MDsnvFarLtaE3G3SwDWjVYd1IQw4lNRCe614PbVd6WQyXcWfLW4PoB%20lVfEMEAgAA)

Comment: Is it possible to group index period by country as well?
let say i have next table
`let t = (datatable(Value:int, Date:datetime, Сountry:string) 
[1000, '2018-01-01', "USA", 
 2000, '2018-01-01', "Israel",
 3000, '2018-01-02', "USA",
 4000, '2018-01-02', "Israel", 
]);`

and i need to get next output:
`1 Jan, USA, 100%
1 Jan, Israel, 100%
2 Jan, USA,  300%
2 Jan, Israel, 200%`